# for loop in R through pre-selected subset of data

Tags: r, loops, subset

For an analysis of the European Social Survey (ESS) I attempt to calculate the the share of respondants having a higher education than their parents. I intend to use a for loop for the calculation. However, I am not able to calculate the shares **for each country and year** seperately. The rows in the dataframe are the individual observations (about 400k) and I have a row indicating the country (cntry) and year (ESSround) of the respondant. My code looks like this

```
for (i in 1:nrow(ESS_cleann)) {


  ESS_cleann$abs_mobility[i] <- ESS_cleann[ESS_cleann[cntry]==i && ESS_cleann[essround]==i] length(ESS_cleann$educ_mobility[i] [ESS_clean$educ_mobility [i] == "U"])/ESS_cleann[ESS_cleann[cntry]==i&& ESS_cleann[essround]==i] length(ESS_cleann$educ_mobility[i]) 
}
```

I am well aware that this is wrong, but I cannot manage to tell R to calculate R the share for each country and year seperately. Help appreaciated a lot!

To give you an idea of the data-structure, these are the heads for all three relevant colums:

```
ESS_cleann.cntry ESS_cleann.essround ESS_cleann.educ_mobility
1               AT                   2                        D
2               AT                   2                        D
3               AT                   3                        U
4               AT                   3                        U
5               AT                   1                        N
6               AT                   3                        N
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Can you provide some sample of your data so we can reproduce the problem? That makes it easier to help. For instance, give use the result of `head(ESS_cleann)`.

Comment: Also, a for loop is probably not a good idea for a calculation of this size.There might be a faster way.

Comment: Futhermore, what exactly goes wrong? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Hey there and thanks for the quick reply. Since the dataset has 1700 variables, I display below a subset of data which contains all necessary variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I understand but are you trying to do something like this?

```r
library(dplyr)

set.seed(2020)

cntry <- sample(c("AT", "UK"), 100, replace = TRUE)
essround <- sample(1:3, 100, replace = TRUE)
mobility <- sample(c("D", "U", "N"), 100, replace = TRUE)

ESS <- data.frame(cntry, essround, mobility)

ESS %>% 
  group_by(cntry, essround, mobility, .drop= FALSE) %>% 
  summarise(counts = n()) %>% 
  mutate(.data = ., perc = counts / sum(counts))
#> # A tibble: 18 x 5
#> # Groups:   cntry, essround [6]
#>    cntry essround mobility counts  perc
#>    <chr>    <int> <chr>     <int> <dbl>
#>  1 AT           1 D             6 0.429
#>  2 AT           1 N             4 0.286
#>  3 AT           1 U             4 0.286
#>  4 AT           2 D             3 0.273
#>  5 AT           2 N             5 0.455
#>  6 AT           2 U             3 0.273
#>  7 AT           3 D             5 0.333
#>  8 AT           3 N             4 0.267
#>  9 AT           3 U             6 0.4  
#> 10 UK           1 D             7 0.318
#> 11 UK           1 N             6 0.273
#> 12 UK           1 U             9 0.409
#> 13 UK           2 D             4 0.25 
#> 14 UK           2 N             7 0.438
#> 15 UK           2 U             5 0.312
#> 16 UK           3 D             7 0.318
#> 17 UK           3 N            10 0.455
#> 18 UK           3 U             5 0.227
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: You're welcome.  As someone commented above in R for loops are often not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Data table sounds like the package you need. You do not provide any data to reproduce the issue but something like this should work:

```
DT[,.SD[ education.level > parent.education.level, .N/nrow(.SD)], by= c("country", "year") ]
```

If you want to do this with a for loop, I guess something like this would work:

```
for (year in years) {
   for (country in countries){
    subtable <- table[year==yer & country===countr]
    store.in.some.variable.or.table.or.something <- nrow( subtable [ education > parental.education, ]) / nrow(subtable)
 } 
}
```

hope this helps.
Best regards
JA.

Comment: applying the code in my case now looks like this: x <-ESS_cleann[,.SD[ educ_mobility=='U', .N/nrow(.SD)], by= .(cntry, essround) ] However, It only returns NaNs and only works through the first 5 rows. Any ideas